# ERROR : Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread [SpringRest]

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, rest

I'm building a service to insert a data in json form into database table.
When I'm posting request in the following form:

```
{"orderID":123,"customerId":44444,"totalAmount":1222.0,"status":"RTGS"}
```

I'm getting the following error :

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path
>   [/oms] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Could not
>   obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread; nested 
>   exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain
>   transaction-synchronized Session for current thread] with root cause
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-
>   synchronized Session for current thread at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
>   at com.exclusively.oms.dao.OrderDAOIml.addOrders(OrderDAOIml.java:31)

My OrderDAOiml.java

```
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.exclusively.oms.entity.Order;

@Repository
public class OrderDAOIml implements OrderDAO{

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OrderDAOIml.class);

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void addOrders(Order o) 
    {
        System.out.println("In Add orders");
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(o);
        logger.info("Orders saved successfully. Orders details = " + o);
    }
}
```

OrderServiceIml.java

```
package com.exclusively.oms.service;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.exclusively.oms.dao.OrderDAO;
import com.exclusively.oms.entity.Order;

@Service("orderService")
public class OrderServiceIml implements OrderService{

    @Autowired
    private OrderDAO orderDAO;

    public void setOrdersDAO(OrderDAO ordersDAO) {
        this.orderDAO = ordersDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public void addOrders(Order o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.orderDAO.addOrders(o);
    }   
}
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.exclusively.oms.controller" />  
 <mvc:annotation-driven />  
 <bean id="dataSource"
 class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
 <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />  
 <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_db" />  
 <property name="username" value="root" />  
 <property name="password" value="root" />  
 </bean>  

 <bean id="sessionFactory"  
 class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
 <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
 <property name="annotatedClasses">  
 <list>  
 <value>com.exclusively.oms.entity.Order</value>  
 </list>  
 </property>  
 <property name="hibernateProperties">  
 <props>  
 <prop    key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>  
  <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>  
 </props>  
 </property>  
 </bean>  

 <bean id="txManager"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">  
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />  
</bean>  

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"  
class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />  
 <bean id="dataDao" class="com.exclusively.oms.dao.OrderDAOIml">    </bean>  
 <bean id="dataServices"      class="com.exclusively.oms.service.OrderServiceIml"></bean>  
 </beans>
```

Comment: I don't see `<tx:annotation-driven />`...

Comment: You have `@Transactional` but aren't instructing Spring to do anything with it.

Comment: what is the solution to it?

Comment: That is in my first comment add `<tx:annotation-driven />`.